# Min and max values of an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the minimum and maximum values of array `A` but I want to exclude all values less than `1e-12`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[9.49108487e-05],
       [1.05634586e-19],
       [5.68676707e-17],
       [1.02453254e-06],
       [2.48792902e-16],
       [1.02453254e-06]])

Min=np.min(A)
Max=np.max(A)
print(Min,Max)
```

The current output is

```
1.05634586e-19 9.49108487e-05
```

The expected output is

```
1.02453254e-06 9.49108487e-05
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice with [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) before getting the min/max:

```
B = A[A>1e-12]
Min = np.min(B)
Max = np.max(B)
print(Min, Max)
```

Output: `1.02453254e-06 9.49108487e-05`

`B`: `array([9.49108487e-05, 1.02453254e-06, 1.02453254e-06])`

Answer (score 2):

You can just select the values of the array greater than `1e-12` first and obtain the min and max of that:

```
>>> A[A > 1e-12].min()
1.02453254e-06
>>> A[A > 1e-12].max()
9.49108487e-05
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = np.array([9.49108487e-05,1.05634586e-19,5.68676707e-17,1.02453254e-06,2.48792902e-16,1.02453254e-06]) 
mask = arr > 1e-12 
Min = np.min(arr[mask]) 
Max = np.max(arr[mask])
```